# Select Only one row where Address Matches

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SQL Server, I have a `Contact` table that contains the name and address of my contacts. I have several instances of multiple contacts living at the same address. When sending my newsletter, I only want to send it to each address one time. How can I modify the query below to only display the first contact at each address?

```
SELECT 
   dbo_Contact.Contact_Title AS Title, 
   dbo_Contact.Contact_FirstName AS [First Name],
   dbo_Contact.Contact_LastName AS [Last Name], 
   dbo_Contact.Contact_Suffix AS Suffix,
   dbo_Contact.Business_Name AS [Business Name], 
   dbo_Contact.Contact_Address1 AS [Address 1],
   dbo_Contact.Contact_Address2 AS [Address 2], 
   dbo_Contact.Contact_City AS City,
   dbo_Contact.Contact_State AS State, 
   dbo_Contact.Contact_Zip AS Zip,
   dbo_Contact.Contact_Email AS Email
FROM 
   dbo_Contact 
INNER JOIN 
   dbo_Mailing_Subscribers ON dbo_Contact.[ContactID] = dbo_Mailing_Subscribers.[ContactID]
WHERE 
   (((dbo_Contact.Contact_Inactive) = False) 
    AND ((dbo_Mailing_Subscribers.Mailing_ID) = True)
    AND ((dbo_Mailing_Subscribers.Subscribed) = True));
```

For example, if Kurt and William live at 123 A Street and Steve lives at 123 B Avenue, I would only want to return records for Kurt and Steve.

Comment: How are you going to determine if they are at the same address?  Street and Zip the same?

Comment: Is this a MS Access Query?  SQL Server does not have a FALSE or TRUE value.

Comment: Yes, to clarify, it is a MS Access Query that is linked to a SQL database.

Comment: You did not specify that, so we gave you an answer that works with TSQL, not MS Access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, here is my solution.

1 - Use table aliases to reduce code foot print.

2 - Changed true/false to 1/0 to meet TSQL Boolean values.

3 - Create RowNum partition by address1, address2, zip code order by last name, first name.

4 - Select only one row from the duplicates.

```
;
with cteData as
(
SELECT 
   C.Contact_Title AS Title, 
   C.Contact_FirstName AS [First Name],
   C.Contact_LastName AS [Last Name], 
   C.Contact_Suffix AS Suffix,
   C.Business_Name AS [Business Name], 
   C.Contact_Address1 AS [Address 1],
   C.Contact_Address2 AS [Address 2], 
   C.Contact_City AS City,
   C.Contact_State AS State, 
   C.Contact_Zip AS Zip,
   C.Contact_Email AS Email,
   row_number() over (partition by Contact_Address1, Contact_Address2, Contact_Zip 
       order by Contact_LastName, Contact_FirstName) as RowNum
FROM 
   dbo_Contact as C
INNER JOIN 
   dbo_Mailing_Subscribers as S 
ON C.[ContactID] = S.[ContactID]
WHERE 
   C.Contact_Inactive = 0 AND
   S.Mailing_ID = 1 AND
   S.Subscribed = 1
)
select * from cteData where RowNum = 1;
```

In short, one mailing will go out to the person with the last / first name closets to A.

Comment: Thanks! Since I'm using an Access front end to my database, I used this query as a stored procedure and created an Access pass-through query. Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

You can do use `row_number()` and a subquery:

```
select <list of columns you want>
from (SELECT row_number() over (partition by Contact_Address1, Contact_Address2, Contact_Zip
                                order by ContactId
                               ) as seqnum
       dbo_Contact.Contact_Title AS Title, 
       dbo_Contact.Contact_FirstName AS [First Name],
       dbo_Contact.Contact_LastName AS [Last Name], 
       dbo_Contact.Contact_Suffix AS Suffix,
       dbo_Contact.Business_Name AS [Business Name], 
       dbo_Contact.Contact_Address1 AS [Address 1],
       dbo_Contact.Contact_Address2 AS [Address 2], 
       dbo_Contact.Contact_City AS City,
       dbo_Contact.Contact_State AS State, 
       dbo_Contact.Contact_Zip AS Zip,
       dbo_Contact.Contact_Email AS Email
    FROM dbo_Contact
    INNER JOIN 
       dbo_Mailing_Subscribers ON dbo_Contact.[ContactID] = dbo_Mailing_Subscribers.[ContactID]
    WHERE 
       (((dbo_Contact.Contact_Inactive) = False) 
        AND ((dbo_Mailing_Subscribers.Mailing_ID) = True)
        AND ((dbo_Mailing_Subscribers.Subscribed) = True))
   ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

It is unclear what you mean by the "same address" and by "the first contact".  For address, the query uses the two address lines and the zip code.  FOr "first contact" the query uses the lowest id in the contact table.

Comment: I do not think TSQL support a Boolean literal.  Also, this query definitely looks like something from MS Access with all the extra parenthesis.